# Oracle SQL Index rebuild failed with recursive error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Failed to rebuild table index in Oracle SQL Developer.

By the way I'm trying to delete from log table some old logs which are older than 2 years.

```
DELETE FROM SCHEME.IP_LOG_TABLE WHERE LOG_DATE <= SYSDATE - interval '2' year
```

I'm getting this error:

> Error starting at line : 1 in command -
>
> DELETE FROM SCHEME.IP_LOG_TABLE WHERE LOG_DATE <= SYSDATE - interval '2' year
>
> Error report -
>
> ORA-01502: index 'SCHEME.PK_IP_LOG_ID' or partition of such index is in unusable state

PK_IP_LOG_ID is unique unusable index with normal index_type that is using ID column.

I try to find in Google how to fix this error and i find this:

> The ORA-01502 error can be easily fixed by issuing the alter index
> index_name rebuild partition partition_name;

But the main problem than i try this:

```
ALTER INDEX PK_IP_LOG_ID REBUILD
```

I get this error that i didn't understand:

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level

Comment: Can you drop the index and then recreate it?

Comment: Are there any other messages, or anything in the database alert log? Or errors doing anything else? It could maybe be a problem with the data dictionary, or running out of space, or something - but there should be more information in the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle was expecting one row but It was getting multiple rows.
I truncated table and inserted only row which has one value.